# Getting "integer required" error while opening in utf-8 else unicode error in python

Tags: python, xml, unicode

I  get the error saying **integer is required**

This is my code:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

file =open('lang.xml','rb',"utf-8")
data=file.read()
file.close()
dom=parseString(data)
xmlTag=dom.getElementsByTagName('child')[0]
print (xmlTag.attributes['name'].value)
```

If I try to read without UTF-8 encoding I get :

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 57: character maps to**

My lang.xml file contains translation in different langauges that I need to fetch based on attribute name..

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know your documentation:

http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/functions.html#open

The documentation clearly tells you that the encoding parameter is optional. It's a keyword parameter - so you must use

```
fp = open(filename, 'rb', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: The fact that it is optional is not the problem here. What is important is that the third parameter is not the encoding but the buffering flag (in both Python 2 and 3). If you are using python 3 than you must either to open(filename, 'rb', encoding='utf-8') or open(filename, 'rb', None, 'utf-8'). If you are using python 2 like most people currently are than there is no encoding option for open().

Comment: I am using python 3.1. however now that I got rid of one error specifying encoding='utf-8' now i get this error

Comment: `File "G:\Python31\parser2.py", line 6
    dom=parseString(data)
  File "G:\Python31\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1937, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "G:\Python31\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "G:\Python31\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 5`

Comment: "not well-formed (invalid token" - obviously your XML is not XML otherwise it would be well-formed and would not cause this error.